# Get H output if positive input is between two thresholds

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, comparator

Is it possible to use an LM311 comparator in a setup similar to this to give H (5V) on COL_EMIT if the positive input is set between, let's say, 2V above and below +12V, and give L (0V) if otherwise? I'm looking to have a potentiometer to regulate the interval size.

On a second note, should I place decoupling capacitors near the inputs of this LM311?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYnANE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is COL_EMIT? The open-collector output? I think you are looking for a "window comparator" which will require two comparators with open-collector outputs wired in OR configuration.

Comment: @Transistor that's a great idea, but how could I change symmetrically the window size (widening or closing it around +12V) when I regulate the potentiometer?

Comment: @ludicrous Set the thresholds with a pullup resistor to +24 (about 25k ohms) and a variable resistor (20k ohms, wiper wired to one terminal) in series with pulldown resistor (25k ohms).   The two terminals of the variable resistor will define a window symmetric about 12V.   Dual comparator LM393 instead of single LM311, of course.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html where the window comparator is explained. You didn't answer or edit your question regarding COL_EMIT.